# Unicode String in urllib.request

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, encoding

The short version: I have a variable `s = 'bär'`. I need to convert `s` to ASCII so that `s = 'b%C3%A4r'`.

Long version:

I'm using `urllib.request.urlopen()` to read an mp3 pronunciation file from URL. This has worked very well, except I ran into a problem because the URLs often contain unicode characters. For example, the German "Bär". The full URL is `https://d7mj4aqfscim2.cloudfront.net/tts/de/token/bär`. Indeed, typing this into Chrome as a URL works, and navigates me to the mp3 file without problems. However, feeding this same URL to `urllib` creates a problem.

I determined this was a unicode problem because the stack-trace reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "importer.py", line 145, in <module>
    download_file(tuple[1], tuple[0], ".mp3")
  File "importer.py", line 81, in download_file
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as in_stream, open(to_fname+ext, 'wb') as out_file: #`with object as name:` safely __enter__() and __exit__() the runtime of object. `as` assigns `name` as referring to the object `object`.
  File "C:\Users\quesm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 162, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\quesm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 465, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\quesm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 483, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Users\quesm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 443, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\quesm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1283, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\quesm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1240, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "C:\Users\quesm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1083, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Users\quesm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1118, in _send_request
    self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)
  File "C:\Users\quesm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 960, in putrequest
    self._output(request.encode('ascii'))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xfc' in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)
```

... and other than the obvious `UnicodeEncodeError`, I can see it's trying to `encode()` to ASCII.

Interestingly, when I copied the URL from Chrome (instead of simply typing it into the Python interpreter), it translated the `bär` to `b%C3%A4r`. When I feed this to `urllib.request.urlopen()`, it processes fine, because all of these characters are ASCII. So my goal is to make this conversion within my program. I tried to get my original string to the unicode equivalent, but `unicodedata.normalize()` in all of its variants didn't work; further, I'm not sure how to store the Unicode as ASCII, given that Python 3 stores all strings as Unicode and thus makes no attempt to convert the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`urllib.parse.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote):

```
>>> urllib.parse.quote('bär')
'b%C3%A4r'
```

---

```
>>> urllib.parse.urljoin('https://d7mj4aqfscim2.cloudfront.net/tts/de/token/',
...                      urllib.parse.quote('bär'))
'https://d7mj4aqfscim2.cloudfront.net/tts/de/token/b%C3%A4r'
```

Comment: Is there a difference between simply concatenating the strings and using `urljoin()`? Also, is there a name for this type of Unicode? Given that the Unicode I got from `normalize()` was completely different, I'm wondering how to name each of them when discussing.

Comment: For your case, it's not strictly required to use `urljoin`. But consider this: `urllib.parse.urljoin('http://example.com/a/b/c', '/x/y/z')`

Comment: It's not a unicode. I heard it's called [Percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Comment: I tried it and it erased the `/a/b/c` part. But changing `/x/y/z` to `x/y/z` made the resulting url different, to `emaple.com/a/b/x/y/z`. I can't really tell what part of the URL will be kept/replaced with this.

Comment: @AlexG, Consider links ('a.html', '/other/place.html') inside some document ('http://example.com/a/b'). `urljoin` is useful to get absolute url of those links.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Thanks for the explanation!