# How can I convert special characters into regular characters (é to e, å to a, etc.)?

Tags: python, string, char, encode

I have a list of songs I am trying to use to search with through YouTube. However, when certain songs with special characters are used, the following error pops up:

Code:

```
import urllib.request
import re

search_kw = tracks[3]['Artist'] + '+' + tracks[3]['Track Title']
search_kw = search_kw.replace(' ','+')

html = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + search_kw)
video_ids = re.findall(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", html.read().decode())
print("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video_ids[0])
```

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 43: ordinal not in range(128)

Example of string that causes error:

```
Tutu Au Mic'  –  dumbéa
```

How can I convert the special characters into regular characters to prevent the error from occurring?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to remove accents (normalize) in a Python unicode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-normalize-in-a-python-unicode-string)

Comment: What is the full traceback of the UnicodeEncodeError?

Comment: Probably the more appropriate solution is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36395705/unicode-string-in-urllib-request

Answer (score 1):

Use the Unidecode library for this: https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/, that guarantees a ascii string in return.

Answer (score 0):

For a web query you probably need to use urlencode

```
urllib.parse.urlencode(query, doseq=False, safe='', encoding=None, errors=None, quote_via=quote_plus)
```

or for general character translations the string maketrans method

```
Python 3.9.5 (default, Nov 18 2021, 16:00:48) 
[GCC 10.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> txt = "Tutu Au Mic' – dumbéa"
>>> mytable = txt.maketrans("é", "e")
>>> print(txt.translate(mytable))
Tutu Au Mic' – dumbea
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this, you should encode the non-ascii characters. Youtube will likely be able to understand what you mean with an ascii approximation, but not all characters have an ascii approximation. And it's not necessary, there are well defined ways to pass non-ascii characters in as part of a URL's query string.

The standard library offers [`urlib.parse.quote_plus`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus) for escaping text to be used as a query string. Or use the excellent `requests` library, https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/.